# Prefix mask into prefix length converstion IPV6

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

I would like to convert subnet mask into prefix length for IPV6.
Let's say I have following IPV6 address with prefix mask:

2001:0DB8:0000:CD30:0000:0000:0000:0000 -> address

FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:0000:0000:0000:0000 -> prefix mask

How can I convert prefix mask into prefix length so the address would be: 2001:0DB8:0000:CD30:0000:0000:0000:0000/64

I found solution for IPV4:

```
int main()
{
    const char *network = "255.255.255.0";
    int n;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, network, &n);
    int i = 0;

    while (n > 0) {
            n = n >> 1;
            i++;
    }

    printf("network = %s, suffix = %d\n", network, i);
}
```

Any C code solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: The mask is 16 bytes (alternatively 8 16-bit values or 4 32-bit values). Check how many "right" bytes are 0. Then check the first byte from the right which is not 0. Check how many low bits are 0...

Comment: You can find the answers by taking a look at the ipcalc project on GitHub: https://github.com/nmav/ipcalc

Comment: IPv6 does not use explicit masks, only prefix lengths. I'm not sure why you have a text representation of an IPv6 mask.